# Usage of RC oscilators

Tags: generator, function-generator

Hello everyone I am looking for usage of RC oscilators but sadly I cannot find them anywhere. That is why I decided to post there my question.

Please provide an answer for all future users of this *Electrical Engineering Stack*.

**The question is:**

*What are the usages of RC sinusoidal oscilators?*

Please post not only the one usage but the list of them.

EDIT:
**The usages which I found:**

1. They are used to generate low frequencies ( mainly audio ).
2. Used in audio signal generators and in electronical music instruments

**Thanks in advance for your help :)**

Comment: Where did you hear of RC generators? What do you think they do? Your question will be closed unless you improve it significantly. Show your research. Can you name any use for one?

Comment: What's a RC generator?

Comment: Ok so in english it is named RC oscilators.

Comment: @transistor Thanks for your response I did some research before but I did not provide the proof so I edited my question. The problem is that I need more examples of it's usage.

Comment: We are not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: @Olin Lathrop as I said its not my homework. Please read carefully before giving downvotes thank you :)

Comment: LOL! Just saying it's not homework is completely meaningless.  On top of that you didn't actually say it wasn't homework, not that it would matter anyway.  The professionals here got their degrees and did plenty of homework in the process, so can spot it quite well.  We know homework when we see it, and your question is just screaming "homework".

Comment: Big thanks for all responses which helped me with understanding what really RC oscilators are. @OlinLathrop It is as meaningless as your insisting that it is a homework. As I said below I am preparing myself to a test so I am gathering all useful informations which will extend my knowledge. I hope that my question will help others as well. I really regard your degrees and that you are professionals, but be more understanding for someone who is starting his adventure with electronics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not true that RC oscillators only generate low frequencies... In microcontrollers, many has internal RC oscillator running at 8Mhz then larger frequencies are obtained by a PLL circuit. The RC internal oscillator is used because it is easy to be implemented by the chip manufacturers, but the reason why its uses are limited is because of its accuracy (capacitance and resistance tend to drift mainly with temperature). pic18f series with internal oscillators has an accuracy of 5% over the whole temperature range. A quartz oscillator circuit can guarantee an accuracy of about 0.01%.
As Florent said, an RC oscillator is just like any oscillator but isn't accurate(microcontrollers have means to calibrate the RC oscilaltor) and its output frequency drifts.

Comment: Ok so to sum up the RC oscillators can be also useful in microcontrollers if the accuracy does not vary am I right?

Comment: true. other than clocking the microcontroller's CPU, the watchdog timer inside the microcontroller and the ADC timer are RC oscillators (they need seperate timers for different functions so the cheapest and smallest in size is an RC oscillator)

Comment: The R-C oscillators used in microcontrollers are astable multivibrators, not sinewave oscillators. Since the question specifies the latter, this answer is not relevant.

Comment: @Dave you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, they are used in electronic music instruments.

The twin-T oscillator for example is used in the very famous [TR-808](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roland_TR-808) drum machine.

RC oscillators can be used in any application where you **don't** need frequency precision and stability, as their frequency vary depending on the temperature for example.
You could use them to clock a microcontroller but it's better not to considering their unstability.

Comment: Thanks but I'm still have to find at least 4-5 usages.

Comment: Is this for a homework? You can think of plenty of usages from what I told you. There is also much information on the internet.

Comment: No it is not for homework, it is for all stack users including me. I will be writing a test and I want to extend my knowlegde.

Comment: Most SMPS use RC osc.

Comment: @Autistic could you proof your comment?